# running 'heroku login' won't create _netrc file

Tags: django, heroku, command-line-interface

I am using on a 64-bit system running Windows 11 with Python 3.7 installed and working in a virtual environment where I have installed Django 3.2. I am trying to deploy my project using Heroku.

I have tried adding heroku cli 64-bit Windows version to various paths. I have set the env variable HOME with a value of `C:/Users/<username>/_netrc`. I have cleaned up the path on each installation so there is only the current path.

When I run heroku login from within my project, I get the following error:

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, open C:/Users/<username>/_netrc
```

Any help here is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> I have set the env variable HOME with a value of `C:/Users/<username>/_netrc`

`HOME` should be a *directory*. Heroku will take care of the `_netrc` part.

Try setting it to `C:/Users/<username>/` instead.

Comment: I had to add myself as a user to the heroku directory with full permissions to get heroku to create the _netrc directory, but it still could not read and was throwing an error of illegal operation reading a directory. I deleted the directory and replaced with a _netrc file. Now it works.

Comment: What do you mean by "the heroku directory"? `_netrc` shouldn't be a directory, it should be a _file_. That's the whole point of my answer: `HOME` defines a _directory_ and `_netrc` is a file in that directory.

Comment: When I installed Heroku, I put it in C:/Users/<username>/. This created a folder named Heroku containing all of the package contents. That folder is where I had to add myself as a user in the folder permissions. _netrc was a folder made the first time I ran heroku login using this permission. I had to delete it and replace it with a file of that name. Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

delete the existing file in path C:/User//**_netrc**
used git bash or terminal for it as i was unable to find the _netrc file in file Explorer.
after deleting It run the below command in project folder.
**heroku git:remote -a <heroku_app_name>**

by running the above command it will create a new _netrc file